# UITabBarController and viewDidLoad

Tags: swift, xcode

Why does viewDidLoad function only called once in UITabBarController's root viewController?

I know viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear can called many times, but why doesn't viewDidLoad called many times?

Comment: why should it be loaded many times? that would make no sense

Answer (score 0):

It's because the tab bar controller gets loaded only one time. That's the process of initialisation and once it's initialised you don't need to do it again. Otherwise it would result in your memory getting loaded with more and more things until you run out of memory.